# How to get local ip address using vb?

Tags: vb.net

How to get ip address in vb.net. i used below code to get local ip address but it showing  dns is not declared. can any one tell me what is that Dns in the Code

**VB Code**

```
Imports System.Environment
Imports System.Net

Public Class Tester
Public Shared Sub Main
Dim hostname As String = Dns.GetHostName()
Dim ipaddress As String = CType(Dns.GetHostByName(hostname).AddressList.GetValue(0), IPAddr
ess).ToString
Console.WriteLine("Computer Name: " & hostname & " IP Address: " & ipaddress)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You know that a machine may have none or several ip addresses?

Comment: now you have changed the question completely - first you asking about `Dns`, now you are asking about iüp of connected client... IF you have a second question you must open a second question and NOT change the first one !!! I rolled back your question to the original one... please upvote/mark as accepted if any answer was of help AND open a second question about "client ip"!

Comment: use dns Class , more information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.dns.aspx Regards.

Comment: obviously someone that does not know to ask a question in a polite, acceptable, civil, human, normal, decent way

Answer (score 6):

Since I get the feeling that, the question (in the title) is not fully answered yet ...

```
Dim hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
For Each hostAdr In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList()

    ' If you just want to write every IP
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " & hostName & " IP Address: " & hostAdr.ToString() 

    ' If you want to look if the device is member of a specific network
    If hostAdr.ToString().StartsWith("192.168.1.") Then DoSomething() : Exit For

    ' I think you get the idea ^^
    ' ...
Next
```

... obviously this is not exactly what the OP asked for, but just from the title and google links, this should answer what people coming here are looking for.

Btw `GetHostByName()`seems to be deprecated, `GetHostEntry()` like this works the same way, without throwing a warning.

Answer (score 2):

`Dns` is a class in the namespace `System.Net` which provides functionality regarding the "Domain Name System" (thus the name `Dns`) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddres
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    For Each hostAdr In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList()

        ' If you just want to write every IP
        'Console.WriteLine("Name: " & hostName & " IP Address: " & hostAdr.ToString())
        Me.RichTextBox1.Text = hostAdr.ToString

        'If you want to look if the device is member of a specific network

        ' ...
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname)

here is a sample code[MSDN](http://goo.gl/RfK0W)

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/VB/Visual-Basic-Code-Snippet-Get-local-computer-IP-address.html) a good example to get the own IP.

```
        Dim _IP As String = Nothing

        Dim _IPHostEntry As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())

        For Each _IPAddress As System.Net.IPAddress In _IPHostEntry.AddressList
            If _IPAddress.AddressFamily.ToString() = "InterNetwork" Then
                _IP = _IPAddress.ToString()
            End If
        Next _IPAddress
        Return _IP
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get local ip address of system using below code:

```
Dim host As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
Dim LocalHostaddress As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList(1).ToString()
```

Comment: Really this is a bad and typicall answer. what happens when the IP that we desire is at index 0 or 2 of 'AddressList()'?

Comment: This would be a better solution, but still not be 100% efficient:             Return (From IP As Net.IPAddress In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList()
                    Where Not IP.ToString.Contains(":")).FirstOrDefault.ToString

Comment: What if a loopback adapter or Bluetooth LAN adapter was installed? You're assuming the network adapter 1 is the correct one without checking. The problem is - the index array starts at 0, not one. There may not even be an adapter 1 in the array. The best way is to foreach iterate through the adapters and [decide] which one is correct by simple means of validation to test for ipv4, ipv6 or bt addresses.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim ipaddress As String =
    Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName).AddressList(0).ToString
```

This will most likely give IPv6 address

And

```
Dim ipaddress As String =
    Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(() => { },
    (ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork)).ToString
```

This will give IPv4 address

My VB is rusty so here is a C# code that works for me.

```
using System.Linq;

using System.Net.Sockets;

string IPaddress =
    Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0].ToString(); //For Ipv6

string IPaddress =
    Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip =>
    ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString(); //For Ipv4
```

I hope this helps.