# How do I get the local IP address of a system?

Tags: vb.net, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get local ip address using vb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212892/how-to-get-local-ip-address-using-vb)

I am using Silverlight3 with VB.NET. I have written the follwing code in my service file. When I run my project locally, it gives the IP address of my system as 192.168.1.12 successfully. But, when I host my project it wont return the IP adress of the system which I am using.

ie: If i host my project in system A which is of ip 192.168.1.12 and if I access the project from system B which is of ip 192.168.1.7, the output of my project will gives the IP of system A (where i have hosted my project). It should give the IP of system B where am running it. Similarly, if am accessing the project from system C means it should give the IP of system C, but here it is returning the IP of system A.

Kindly help me please.
Thanks

```
Private Function fnLocalIp() As String
    Try
        Dim h As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName)
        Dim strLocalIp As String = h.AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString
        Return strLocalIp
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212892/how-to-get-client-system-ip-address-using-vb

Comment: and then he changes the original question completely, what kind of sucker is this?

Answer (score 5):

You can get local ip using below code:

in vb.net:

```
Dim host As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
Dim LocalHostaddress As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList(1).ToString()
```

In c#:

```
string host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string LocalHostaddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

use dns Class , more information here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.dns.aspx

Regards.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. it is returning Static ip as 122.166.48.230. i want local ip which is like 192.168.1.12